# How to prepare data for table representation?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is an array of data:

```
  let data = {
    country: "France",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2020,
    value: 5507888,
    rownum: 108
  },
 {
    country: "France",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5507888,
    rownum: 108
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2020,
    value: 5849610,
    rownum: 108
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5849610,
    rownum: 108
  },
  {
    country: "Spain",
    productType: "Gain",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5849610,
    rownum: 108
  }
]
```

I need to represent data for table form (Angular):

```
Fruits
   France       2020     2021
   Germany      2020     2021
Gain                
   Spain        2020     2011
```

I have tried to group data first by `productType`. Then I need to group by county. Problem is the countries are repeated in each product type.

```
function groupBy(list, keyGetter) {
    const map = new Map();
    list.forEach((item) => {
         const key = keyGetter(item);
         const collection = map.get(key);
         if (!collection) {
             map.set(key, [item]);
         } else {
             collection.push(item);
         }
    });
    return map;
}
```

`const grouped = groupBy(filtered, pet => pet.productType); console.log(grouped);`

Comment: Are you just to get a grouped data(group by productType) from your original data? If so,you can use `reduce()` to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group by `productType`,below is a reference for you

```js
let data = [{
    country: "France",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2020,
    value: 5507888,
    rownum: 108
  },
 {
    country: "France",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5507888,
    rownum: 108
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2020,
    value: 5849610,
    rownum: 108
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5849610,
    rownum: 108
  },
  {
    country: "Spain",
    productType: "Gain",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5849610,
    rownum: 108
  }
]

let result = data.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let type = c.productType
  a[type] = a[type]??[]
  
  let record = a[type].find(i => i.country == c.country)
  if(record){
    record.year.push(c.year)
  }else{
    a[type].push({country:c.country,year:[c.year]})
  }
  return a
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What if exist another object for France but with different year?

```{
    country: "France",
    productType: "Fruits",
    units: "USD",
    year: 2021,
    value: 5507888,
    rownum: 108
  }```

Comment: @Dalama do you want to group by productType and year together?

Comment: I need to show type of product , then list of countries and against the values by years, like I posted in question

Comment: @Dalama I think my answer meets your demand,have you tested it?It would be better if you can add more source data and expected result

Comment: I have added more values in input array and edited the table representation I expect

Comment: @Dalama Based on your new data I have updated my answer,you can check it again!